# Rounding issue in C (32 bit)

Tags: c, visual-studio

Given the following C code snippet:

```
printf("value: %lf\n", (double) ceil(((double) 100) / ((double) 2)));
```

When compiling this code with Visual Studio 2010 C compiler in **64 bit** and running it afterward, it gives the expected result:

```
value: 50.000000
```

However, when compiling the same code with Visual Studio 2010 C compiler this time in **32 bit** and running it afterward, it gives an unexpected result:

```
value: 1028.000000
```

Any hints why this unexpected value?

Comment: What do the compiler warnings say?

Comment: No warnings in both compilations.

Comment: Maybe because the `l` format  modifier is not specified for a `%f` formatting conversion, according to my reference, and so your C library interprets the corresponding parameter as something else.

Comment: Cant' reproduce, I also get 50

Comment: I tried both with `%lf` and `%f` and it's same (i.e. it gives an unexpected value in **32 bit**).

Comment: Sorry, I meant `%f` (I have edited my previous comment).

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis: with Visual Studio 2010 32 bit C compiler and using the `ceil` function (without it, the code works as expected)?

Comment: @user7698505 ah sorry, didn't notice the older version.

Comment: What's with all that casting and extra parens? `printf("value: %f\n", ceil(100.0 / 2.0));` is all you need. (I assume your real code has slightly different numbers because otherwise why even bother with the `ceil()` and division instead of a literal 50.0?)

Comment: This should be easy to narrow things down. Start by seeing what `printf("value: %f\n", 50.0);` gives you. This will determine the problem to be either with printf's formatting, or the mathematical calculations. Then go from there. This is what debugging is all about. You should be able to determine the root cause of this all by yourself.

Comment: You should show a [mcve] program, not just a single line, btw.

Comment: did you include math.h?

Comment: @Shawn: to make sure that all numbers are treated as double and operations are done in double. Your suggestion (which I tried before posting this issue in SO) does not work. It gives `value: 0.000000`.

Comment: @user7698505 could you please run `printf("value: %f\n", ceil(100.0l / 2.0l));` and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: the code `printf("value: %f\n", 50.0);` gives the expected result `value: 50.000000`.

Comment: `100.0` *is* a double literal. Casting an integer literal to a double just adds unnecessary clutter.

Comment: I bet @phuclv is on to something, though. Provide a complete compilable program that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @phuclv: you suggestion solved the issue. Can you post it as an answer so that I can elect it as a correct solution for the issue? Thanks to everyone that helped with suggestions!

Comment: Why is this C question tagged with `c++`?

Comment: Indeed. This code **cannot** compile in C++ and present the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above, you forgot to `#include <math.h>` and that leads to undefined behavior

I believe if you turn on all warnings you'll get the root cause right away